# Problems when overriding a method from a templated base class

Tags: c++

In a class derived from a base templated class, I override a method `createType()`. When I try to access `createType(int)` of the derived class, the compiler says that it does not exist.  Why?

```
template <class T>
class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual T createType(){ return T(); }
    virtual T createType(int){ return T(); }
};

class Point
{
public:
    float x, y;
};

class PointFactory : public BaseClass<Point>
{
public:
    virtual Point createType() { return BaseClass::createType(); }
};

int main()
{
    PointFactory pf;
    auto p = pf.createType(5); // error here
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is

> error C2660: 'PointFactory::createType' : function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *complete* error message, in full, unedited, and with any possible informational notes.

Comment: You should use `override` if you  override.

Comment: i just wrote down this example just to be able to clearly expose the problem, the actual implementation is a very large code and uses just classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`virtual Point PointFactory::createType()` hides the base overloads.

You may add `using BaseClass<Point>::createType;` to fix that:

```
class PointFactory : public BaseClass<Point>
{
public:
    using BaseClass<Point>::createType; // unhide overloads

    Point createType() override { return BaseClass::createType(); }
};
```

Comment: Beaten me by 8 seconds! :) I will remove my answer.

Comment: could you please describe to me how to declare it inside the class declaration and outside of it, thank you

Comment: perfect, thank you. do you have a link when i can find some more info on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the overriding, you have two other problems:

1. You call the child-class function with an argument, but the child-class has no member function with that name that takes an integer argument.
2. `return T;`? If `T` was e.g. `int` then that would be `return int;`, how would you expect that to work? That will cause the functions in the base class not exist, and could give you a similar error to what you ask about once you `override` the function.

Comment: i just wrote down this example just to be able to clearly expose the problem, the actual implementation is a very large code and uses just classes

Comment: @fatehmtd Unrelated errors distract from the actual problem, especially since both problems I describe could give you error messages similar to the overriding error. That's why it's so important to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and in the case of build errors create one containing only the error you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

It may be clearer to examine the error reported by g++:

> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings    -c -o 36315450.o 36315450.cpp
> 36315450.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> 36315450.cpp:24:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘PointFactory::createType(int)’
>      auto p = pf.createType(5); // error here
>                              ^
> 36315450.cpp:24:29: note: candidate is:
> 36315450.cpp:18:19: note: virtual Point PointFactory::createType()
>      virtual Point createType() { return BaseClass::createType(); }
>                    ^
> 36315450.cpp:18:19: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
> make: *** [36315450.o] Error 1
> ```

Because you override `createType()`, then `createType(int)` is shadowed.  It will not be accessible unless you re-implement it in your derived class, perhaps using `using`:

```
class PointFactory : public BaseClass<Point>
{
public:
    virtual Point createType() { return Point(0,0); }
    using BaseClass<Point>::createType;
};
```

I've made the overriding `createType()` do something other than pass through to the base class, as otherwise it would be redundant here!